# Scroll a color line along with a circle along the background line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a block on the page where there is a background line, on the line itself there is a circle that scrolls along with the main scroll

The question is, how can you make it so that, along with the circle, another line of the same color as the circle scrolls along the line, and it all would look something like this

[image]

```js
const circle = document.querySelector(".circle");
const cases = document.querySelectorAll(".case");

circle.style.transition = ""

const handleScroll = () => {
  const {
    height: blockHeight
  } = document.querySelector(".block2").getBoundingClientRect()

  const maxTop = cases[cases.length - 1].offsetTop + cases[cases.length - 1].offsetHeight - 200
  const minTop = cases[0].offsetTop

  let {
    height: startTop
  } = cases[0].getBoundingClientRect()

  const scrollDist = Math.min(maxTop, Math.max(startTop / 2 + window.scrollY, minTop))

  circle.style.top = `${scrollDist}px`
  circle.style.backgroundSize = `17px ${blockHeight}px`
  circle.style.backgroundPosition = `0 ${-scrollDist}px`
}

const handleWindowSizeAndScroll = () => {
  window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
  window.removeEventListener("resize", handleScroll)
  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
  window.addEventListener("resize", handleScroll)
}

handleScroll()
handleWindowSizeAndScroll()
window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowSizeAndScroll)
```

```css
.block1 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.block3 {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.block2 {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.block2,
.block2 .circle {
  background: linear-gradient(214deg, rgba(79, 142, 255, 0) 0%, #f5e550 10%, #f5e550 90%, rgba(79, 142, 255, 0) 100%) center/3px calc(100% - 100px) no-repeat;
}

.block2 .circle {
  background: #4f8eff;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.block2 .circle,
.block2 .circle::before {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.block2 .circle::before {
  content: "";
  inset: 3px;
  background-color: white;
}

.block2 .circle::before {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 3px;
  height: 40vh;
  background: #4f8eff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 20vh 10vh -10vh #f6e75e, inset 0 -20vh 10vh -10vh #f6e75e;
  z-index: 2;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 200px 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-t4GWSVZO1eC8BM339Xd7Uphw5s17a86tIZIj8qRxhnKub6WoyhnrxeCIMeAqBPgdZGlCcG2PrZjMc+Wr78+5Xg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="block2">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="case">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 1</div>
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 2</div>
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="case">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 3</div>
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-5 text">Text 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block3"></div>
```

Comment: I was half way through answering your last question before you deleted it, **Bootstrap tab bar smoothly move navigation**, anyway here is working jsfiddle solution for it if you still need it... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/7f4j90nz/4/

Comment: @joshmoto thank you very much, please answer in this post, I will count the answer for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76636704/bootstrap-tab-bar-smoothly-move-navigation-buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with the behaviour you ar looking for using [sticky positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to keep the circle fixed in the viewport during scrolling. This requires no JS.

I made the gradient line with inset [box-shadows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) on the `.circle` element. The circle is made with a pseudo element `.circle::after` :

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 500vh;
  margin-bottom: 80vh;
  background: #eee;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  background: #f6e75e;
  z-index: 1;
}

.circle {
  position: sticky;
  top: 30vh;
  left: 50%;
  width: 3px;
  height: 40vh;
  background: #4f8eff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 20vh 10vh -10vh #f6e75e, inset 0 -20vh 10vh -10vh #f6e75e;
  z-index: 2;
}

.circle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #4f8eff;
  background: #fff;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: -10px auto auto -10px;
  z-index: 2;
}

*/
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```